# get https response from scrapy shell

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell, crawlera

I have a spider that is getting cookies from a site in the first few steps. I would like to get the cookies, start the scrape, and if the HTTP status of the current request == 302, I want to loop back to the cookies part to refresh them. How can I log the HTTP status as a variable in scrapy shell, to add in an "if http_status ==302, break and go back to step 1"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. If anyone comes across this, all you have to do it set your variable (in my case http_response) to response.status. so http_response = response.status returns '200' or whatever depending on the status of the current request. lol solved.